# Замена значений в dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет,
У меня следующая проблема, есть последовательность

```
90359   0
90360   0
90361   0
90362   0
90363   0
90364   0
90365   2
90366   2
90367   2
90368   2
90369   2
90370   2
90371   2
90372   0
90373   0
90374   0
90375   0
90376   0
```

Мне нужно оставить первые три двойки, а остальные заменить на 0. Т.е. получить вот это:

```
90359   0
90360   0
90361   0
90362   0
90363   0
90364   0
90365   2
90366   2
90367   2
90368   0
90369   0
90370   0
90371   0
90372   0
90373   0
90374   0
90375   0
90376   0
```

При этом встречаются последовательности этих двоек разной длины, может 5 подряд, может 10.
И все их нужно привести к длине 3.
Доп. вопрос. Также встречаются одинокие двойки в этом же dataframe, возможно ли их заменить на 0?
Помогите, плиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `loc[]` отбираем строки по двум условиям (булевым массивам) - а) для групп двоек больше 3-х штук подряд и б) для "одиноких" двоек.

Условие а): `df.col1.eq(2) & df.groupby(df.col1.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().gt(2)` - истинно если в колонке `col1` двойка и порядковый номер двойки в группе больше 2х (нумерация с 0). В конструкции `df.groupby(df.col1.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().gt(2)` сначала сформированы номера групп с одинаковыми числами (`.diff().ne(0).cumsum()`) вида 000111222333, затем они сгруппированы и числа в каждой группе пронумерованы (`.cumcount()`) от 0 до n, после чего порядковым номерам от 0 до 2 поставлен в соответствие (`.gt(2)`) false, а номерам от 3 до n - true.

Условие б): `(df.col1.eq(2) & df.col1.shift(-1).ne(2) & df.col1.shift(1).ne(2))` - истинно, когда ни снизу (`.shift(1).ne(2)`) ни сверху (`.shift(-1).ne(2)`) от двойки (`.eq(2)`) нет двоек.

Условия а и б (булевы массивы) объединены оператором ИЛИ, поэтому при истинности любого из них соответствующим строкам в колонке `col1` присваивается 0:
`df.loc[<условие (булев массив)>, 'col1'] = 0`

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\test\df.csv') # ваш файл с датасетом
df.loc[(df.col1.eq(2) & df.groupby(df.col1.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().gt(2)) | (df.col1.eq(2) & df.col1.shift(-1).ne(2) & df.col1.shift(1).ne(2)), 'col1'] = 0
print(df[df.col1.eq(2)].head(20))
```

Вывод (отфильтровал только двойки, первые 20 строк)

```
      id  col1
38    38     2
39    39     2
44    44     2
45    45     2
61    61     2
62    62     2
63    63     2
92    92     2
93    93     2
127  127     2
128  128     2
129  129     2
172  172     2
173  173     2
174  174     2
195  195     2
196  196     2
197  197     2
211  211     2
212  212     2
```

1. Двойки остаются
2. Групп двоек больше 3-х  и "одиноких" нет

Comment: В Вашем коде тоже самое на данном примере работает, вставляю в свой большой dataset получаю просто замену всех двоек на нули. Столбцы переименовал. Всё сделал один в один. У меня индексы это и есть первый столбец, т.е. 'id' . Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Обновил ответ. У меня все отработало на вашем датасете

Comment: Я сейчас скопировал Ваш код и у меня тоже всё отработало отлично, хотя код тот же. У меня уже какие-то глюки. Спасибо, большое.

Answer (score 0):

при исходном фрейме (я добавил разнообразия):

```
        0  1
0   90359  0
1   90360  2
2   90361  0
3   90362  3
4   90363  0
5   90364  0
6   90365  2
7   90366  2
8   90367  2
9   90368  2
10  90369  2
11  90370  2
12  90371  2
13  90372  0
14  90373  0
15  90374  2
16  90375  2
17  90376  0
18  90377  2
19  90378  2
20  90379  2
21  90380  0
```

я бы сделал так:

```
chgidx = []
# сначала получаем группы двоек, идущих подряд
for i, g in df[df[1]==2].groupby((df[1].shift() != df[1]).cumsum()):
# если в группе количество двоек 3 и более, берем первые 3 индекса группы
# остальные индексы игнорируем. заносим полученные индексы в список
    if len(g)>2:
        chgidx.extend(g.index[:3])

# меняем ВСЕ двойки на 0
df.loc[df[1]==2, 1] = 0
# по списку с полученными индексами меняем 0 на двойки в нужных местах
df.loc[chgidx, 1] = 2
```

получаем df:

```
        0  1
0   90359  0
1   90360  0
2   90361  0
3   90362  3
4   90363  0
5   90364  0
6   90365  2
7   90366  2
8   90367  2
9   90368  0
10  90369  0
11  90370  0
12  90371  0
13  90372  0
14  90373  0
15  90374  0
16  90375  0
17  90376  0
18  90377  2
19  90378  2
20  90379  2
21  90380  0
```

Comment: В данном конкретном случае код работает, переношу на свой огромный dataset, ничего не работает. Что то с индексацией, он просто заменяет все двойки на нули. В моем datasetе первый столбец это индексы, но даже если я выношу индексы как отдельный столбец все равно не работает. А для чего переменная i в 'for i, g in df[df[1]==2].groupby((df[1].shift() != df[1]).cumsum())'?

Comment: Приведите часть своего датасета. Можно даже на файлообменнике. Переменная i  получает ключ группы из группировки, потому что группировка отдаёт ключи и группы. В данном конкретном случае она не нужна.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--C-RVrsEDfHIJkv9Yglsmiwydo8PtNK/view?usp=sharing